# How to add libzip as dependency in meson build system

Tags: archlinux, meson-build, libzip, gnome-builder

I'm building a small app using gtk+-3.0 in Gnome Builder, but I want to use libzip for some functions. But apparently meson is not accepting to add libzip. See my snippet:

```
foo_deps = [
  dependency('libzip', version: '>= 1.5.0'),
  dependency('gio-2.0', version: '>= 2.50'),
  dependency('gtk+-3.0', version: '>= 3.22')
]
```

This is my error message:

```
../../../../../../Projetos/foo/src/meson.build:8:0: ERROR: Dependency "libzip" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake
```

But libzip IS listed as a pkgconfig package:

```
[vinicius@maclinux ~]$ pkg-config --list-all | grep libzip
libzip                         libzip - library for handling zip archives
```

And:

```
[vinicius@maclinux ~]$ pkg-config --libs libzip
-lzip
```

Finally:

```
[vinicius@maclinux ~]$ ls -l /usr/include | grep zip.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  26491 mar  2  2021 zip.h
```

I'm stucked. I couldn't find any help in internet regarding libzip using together meson. I tried to just ommit libzip and a dependency but meson complains that it can't find zip.h.

I am running this in ArchLinux.

[UPDATE] If I compile manually using meson, it works. The problem occurs only inside GNOME Builder.

Answer (score 1):

If you *can* build directly with meson and *cannot* with GNOME builder - this points to missing **PKG_CONFIG_PATH** configuration in the latter case, i.e. environment variable with the list of paths where *.pc (pkg config files) are searched.

Check where libzip.pc is located:

```
$ apt-file search libzip.pc
$ libzip-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libzip.pc
```

I've never used GNOME builder but I found the following documentation page: [Use Custom Sysroot](https://builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/sysroot.html?highlight=PKG_CONFIG_PATH#use-a-custom-sysroot).

> By default pkg-config will search in /lib/pkgconfig and
> /usr/lib/pkgconfig but some sysroots install them in different
> locations. Debian-based use paths such as
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig. Other systems may use paths such
> as /usr/lib64/pkgconfig.

So, if libzip.pc in none of above, you should

> ... configure a new sysroot in Preferences -> SDKs to allow Builder to
> use it.

and it will land to  *~/.config/gnome-builder/sysroot/general.conf*

PS
It could be also useful to check where all *.pc files located:

```
$ for f in $(locate *.pc); do dirname $f; done | uniq
```

and add these paths according to above.

Answer (score 0):

If this a flatpak environment, you have to install `libzip` there. Open the flatpak JSON file and add your library to the `modules` section. Then it will be available in flatpak.